# Retain Query String In URL

Tags: query-string

I've built a web app that lives on SharePoint.

The user is asked a question at the beginning. They can answer either "Yes" or "No."

A query string is added to the URL depending on the user's answer. So there will only be two query strings: `?choice=yes` or `?choice=no`.

The `index.html` page has this:

```
<input type="button" value="Yes" onclick="redirect(this);" id="yes" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
<input type="button" value="No" onclick="redirect(this);" id="no" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```

And this is how the query string is initially added:

```
function redirect(e){

    location.href = "map.html?choice=" + e.id;

}
```

After the user picks an answer it takes them to `map.html`, which is the first section the user comes into from the question (so the URL at this point can be either `map.html?choice=yes` or `map.html?choice=no`). After that, they can navigate to where ever they please on the app.

Here's the issue. The navigation is being pulled in from an external `nav.js` file (i.e. js include) like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/nav.js"></script>
```

Here's the `nav.js` code:

```
document.write(
'   <div class="row text-center navigation">' +
'     <ul class="nav nav-pills">' +
'      <li id="nav-welcome"><a class="align" href="index.html">WELCOME</a></li>' +
'      <li id="nav-map"><a href="map-uor.html"><span>MAP</span></a></li>' +
'      <li id="nav-about"><a href="annual-passes-FLRAP.html"><span>ABOUT</span></a></li>' +
'      <li id="nav-contact"><a href="tickets-express.html"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>' +
'      <li id="nav-pricing"><a href="park-tickets01.html"><span>PRICING</span></a></li>' +
'    </ul>' +
'   </div>'
);
```

How do I continue to pass either query string as the user continues to navigate the app?

There is a single page who's content will change depending on the query string.

So if the user answers "yes" at the beginning and eventually navigates to the pricing page, it will pull content specific to the "yes" answer (i.e. call a specific function).

If the user answers "no" at the beginning and eventually navigates to the pricing page, it will pull content specific to the "no" answer (i.e. call a specific function).

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You could set a cookie with javascript code

Comment: @MarkE So can I set the query string at the beginning, then use the cookie to carry it through? Or forego the query string and just use a cookie?